# How to configure nginx docker image to work as forward proxy for asp.net core Web API

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nginx, .net-core

Below is the command I am using to run nginx image

```
docker run --name docker-nginx -p 8989:8989 -v ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf -d nginx
```

Below the configuration of my default.conf

```
server {
    listen 8989;
    server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8443;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

When i go to localhost:8989. I get `502 bad gateway`

Comment: Your `proxy_pass` is most likely wrong. In the Nginx container, `localhost` means the container itself. I don't imagine you have anything listening on port 8443 inside the Nginx container.

Comment: I am running api on 8443 locally on my PC.

Comment: Can you suggest me some changes or possible steps to resolve this issue